# Efficient implementation of an iPod-like shuffle algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, random, shuffle

The goal is to pick a random song from 1..N with no repetitions for N songs, and be able to iterate forward and back like in an iPod. I used a hash table to store random songs. Is there a better way?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: It is a bit hard to write this without knowing what you are writing in!

Comment: What do you mean with iterate forward and back?

Comment: The iPod actually creates a temporary playlist (I believe) for it's random play hence the reason you are able to move back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use an LCG based pseudo random number generator to choose songs. At every step song n+1 is (an+b)Mod 2^N. make sure that period of the LCG is above N. Iterate backwards using the inverse of the LCG

Comment: Interesting idea. How to ensure that the period is greater than N?

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#cite_note-HullDobell-3

Comment: Doesn't this give a decidedly non-random permutation of the songs?

Answer (score 4):

One simple algorithm for doing this would be to start off with a list of all N songs and then randomly shuffle the array elements using an algorithm like the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).  Once you've done that, you will have an ordering of all the songs in a random order and with no duplicates.  If you keep track of your current index in the list, you can then implement next and previous by just moving forwards or backwards in the array.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So O(NlogN) to shuffle and O(N) space to lookup the array?

Comment: @McDowells- Actually, only O(n) to do the shuffle (Fisher-Yates runs in O(n) time), then only O(1) lookup times in the array.  You do need to use O(n) memory to hold the shuffled order, though.

Comment: Shuffle an array of the indexes, less expensive in memory.

Comment: @arynaq swapping two object references is not too expensive (and not many people use C/C++ or PHP 4.x nowadays).